# Android: Can hide soft keyboard at cursor position?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Here is my question!

I have an editText field with maximum character is 1.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:maxLength="1"/>
```

Then I call soft keyboard and input a character.
Is it possible to **automatically hide keyboard** after one character entered?
If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: used `TextChangeListener()` for that..

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`hideSoftInputFromWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29)** to **hide** the soft keyboard, it is inside **[`InputMethodManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29)**. But remember you have to pass the **token of your window**, which you can obtain by calling [**`getWindowToken`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowToken())() from your edit. 
So you final code should look like something like this:

```
EditText myEdit= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final int maxTextLength = 1;//max length of your text

    InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxTextLength);
    myEditText.setFilters(filterArray);

    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){


   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence txtWatcherStr, int start, int before, int count){
       if(count==maxTextLength ){
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tvSecondary.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if(tvSecondary.getText().toString().length()>0)
        {
            add your hide-keyboard code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {

    }
});
```